# ReactJS commenting system structure for something like Facebook Posts

Tags: reactjs

I have posts on my page, and for the commenting section I have a ReactJS <CommentSection /> component. There will be 10 posts loaded initially; I know how to render the CommentSection for those posts. How can I attach the CommentSection component when the posts loaded from the server again?

I do not know the best practices. Think of facebook posts: when you scroll down the posts are loded dynamically.

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.content}</div>;
}
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.each( $('.post .commentForm'), function(key, elem) {
        console.log(elem)
        React.render(<CommentForm content="Bla" />, elem);
    });
});
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8907/

Comment: Please include your current code

Comment: have a look at this @FakeRainBrigand https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8907/

Comment: This doesn't show how you're loading posts from the server, or if you already have infinite scroll working, or where the actual content prop comes from.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9865/ Please have a look at this, Imaging the button as the button you click to get more posts, and then once the posts are here how do i set up the commentForm to that each post

Comment: Run the same code you ran initially, but change `$('.post .commentForm')` to something that only matches the newly added elements. This isn't normal use of react; try rewriting the comment list as a component, and fetch data from the server, not html.

Comment: If you don't know the best practices, by far the best thing you can do for yourself is take out the 30~60 minutes this weekend to actually just run through the "getting started" tutorial on http://facebook.github.io/react, because it's really good. Just read the text, write the code, run the server, see what it does, work your way through, and an hour later you will have learned a ton, and may even now understand how to answer your own question (and don't skip things because "I know this already", just do them. Don't lie to yourself)